# Cloud Function response stream

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, node-archiver

I have a script that is building a zip file on demand.  It's working great locally using the Cloud Functions Local Emulator.  When deployed, it's not streaming the response.  The whole zip response is built, then sent. I know this is happening because the content-length response header is being set, which is not happening locally.

How can I get Cloud Functions to stream the response?

```
exports.zip = (req, res) => {
    const zipRequest = {
        media: [{
            'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...',
            'file': 'file1.jpg'
        }, {
            'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...',
            'file': 'file2.jpg'
        }, {
            'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...',
            'file': 'file3.jpg'
        }],
        filename: 'photos.zip'
    };

    res.attachment(zipRequest.filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');

    let zip = Archiver('zip');
    zip.on('end', () => {
      res.end();
    });

    zip.pipe(res);
    zipRequest.media.forEach((file) => {
        zip.append(request.get(file.url), { name: file.name });
    });

    zip.finalize();
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or it simply does not stream the response? It looks there is nothing about streaming response but request mentioned in the public documentation at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently there is no way to stream the response as it will be buffering the response due to how the infrastructure is implemented and there's no way around it right now, which means it would not see the results until the response is closed.

Comment: 2021, is this still the case?

Comment: yes this is still the case in 2021 for cloud fumctions

Comment: I wish they had of told me this before I spent a day trying to get it working

Comment: August, 2022. Having similar issue. Will this be fixed?

Comment: @Witek there is nothing to fix because this is not a bug. It is simply a feature which is currently not supported.

Comment: @guenhter it might be a bug. The code that reads and handles the `cache-control` header isn't working! Anyway...its pretty clear he's asking "when will it be implemented?"

Comment: Still the case in September 2023? If so, I guess we'll have to go the Cloud Run route: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming