# Firebase functions get SSE stream and return SSE to client

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I would like to know if Firebase functions can get a data from an EventSource of another provider and return as SSE for client? For example, the function get SSE from OpenAI and return to client as an EventSource.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to stream data through a Google Cloud Function until this day. You can only see the results when the response ends.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431968

I'm trying to do the same thing you are. Realtime Database can be an option to stream the events to the client.